# How to use mixins in .scss files in node_modules into our .tsx or .jsx for styling

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, scss-mixins

I have a .scss file in one of installed node_modules. I want to import that scss file into .tsx file for the styling of a component that I am trying to create.
@mixin make-embedded-control($className: embedded-control){.....}
The scss file has the following mixin that has all the css classes that I intend to use it in my .tsx file but normal import is not working.
Due to compliance issues I am not able to share source code.
I am new to scss so I would be glad if anyone can help out.

Comment: Doesn't `@include` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use mixin in typescript.
To use a scss file in Typescript you have to:

Install SASS and its typing file if you are using typescript.

```
npm i -D node-sass
npm i -D @types/node-sass
```

Import scss file in your .ts

```
import './style.scss';
```